# Find matrices $X$ such that the diagonal of $X^H X$ is sparse

Tags: matrices, reference-request, optimization, matrix-rank, non-convex-optimization

I want to find matrices $X$ such that the diagonal of $X^H X$, where $X^H$ is the Hermitian transpose of $X$, is sparse — as many zeros as possible. Intuitively, $X$ should have many empty columns.

I guess this is one of the sparse matrix recovery problems, but I have trouble describing this constraint in a way that could make it amenable to existing algorithms. Can someone please give me pointers to papers/software?

Comment: nuclear norm or trace norm

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add `reference-request` to your tags.

Comment: Why not use the *zero* matrix?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo there are other constraints of course. I was hoping to encourage solutions that have empty row/columns, not just sparse. $X^HX$ being sparse does not fully convey my requirement here.

Comment: So, what constraints do you have?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it's mainly bounding the inner product of the columns in X with other known vectors.

Comment: Anyway, after more reading, I think group sparsity constraints may be what I am after.

Comment: Hard to give good advice without the full picture.